# Hardy-Ramanujan theorem's "purely elementary reasoning"

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization

I'm reading through *The normal number of prime factors of a number $n$*. I'm confused by a remark on the [second page](http://www.imsc.res.in/%7Erao/ramanujan/CamUnivCpapers/Cpaper35/page2.htm): let $f(n)$ represent the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. Then

> we can shew (by purely elementary reasoning) that, if $\epsilon$ is any positive number, we have
>
> $$ f(n) < (1 + \epsilon) \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$$
> for all sufficiently large values of $n$ and
> $$ f(n) > (1 - \epsilon) \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$$
> for an infinity of values; so that the maximum order of $f(n)$ is
> $$ \frac{\log n}{\log \log n} $$

I don't follow their "purely elementary reasoning." What am I missing?

Comment: This remark only meant for the case that $n=p_1\cdots p_k$ is the product of the first $k$ primes, i.e., with $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the facts that $\forall\epsilon>0$
  holds $$1<\frac{\pi\left(x\right)\log\left(x\right)}{\theta\left(x\right)}<1+\epsilon$$
 for all sufficiently large values of $x$
 . Now if we take a sufficiently large $n$
  of the form $$n=p_{1}p_{2}\cdots p_{k}$$
  we have$$f\left(n\right)=k=\pi\left(p_{k}\right)$$
 and$$\theta\left(p_{k}\right)=\underset{i\leq k}{\sum}\log\left(p_{i}\right)=\log\left(n\right).$$