# What is the "purely elementary reasoning" that the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ grows like $\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

At the top of the second page of [this](http://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/CamUnivCpapers/Cpaper35/page2.htm) paper by Ramanujan, he states that "by purely elementary reasoning", where $f(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$, we have that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, 
$$
f(n) < (1+\varepsilon)\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}
$$
for all sufficiently large $n$, and 
$$
f(n) > (1-\varepsilon) \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}
$$
for infinitely many values of $n$, so that the maximum order of $f(n)$ is
$$
\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}.
$$
What's the simple reason for this he had in mind?

Thanks.

Edit: notation clarified per Thomas Andrews' comment.

Comment: In older mathematical writing, "elementary" didn't necessarily mean "simple" - it just meant that the result in question could be proven with real-analytic techniques (as opposed to complex-analytic).

Comment: I'm not sure that $\sim$ is the right symbol, at least as usually used. But it might be an upper bound.

Comment: my first thought is that the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem says that there are roughly ${N}\over{log(n)}$ primes up to N and maybe taking the log of this results in the formula ?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Interesting, thanks.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think you're right, and have edited the question.

Comment: Is this asking the same thing as this older question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103861/hardy-ramanujan-theorems-purely-elementary-reasoning?rq=1

Comment: @TannerSwett It is, yes, thank you. I didn't see it when searching before posting.

Answer (score 1):

$\omega(n)$ is maximized by primorials, and by the prime number theorem $p_k\sim k\log k$
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n}p_k = \exp\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log p_k \stackrel{\text{Stirling}}{\sim}\exp\left(n\log n + n\log\log n\right)$$
so $\omega(n)<(1+\varepsilon)\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$ follows by considering primorials. On the other hand the square-free numbers have a positive density ($\frac{6}{\pi^2}$) in $\mathbb{N}$ and loosely speaking the previous bound does not change by much if a primorial is replaced by a square-free number with a lot of small prime factors. The bound $\omega(n)>(1-\varepsilon)\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$ can so be achieved by considering square-free numbers.